# How to determine if cloned item's source item has changed?

Tags: sitecore

I would like to have a notification for all cloned items when its source item has changed in the content editor.

I understand that I can use the pipeline to do this.

What item property can i use to compare if there is any changes between cloned item and source item.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/02/Identify-Cloned-Items-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Publishing-Target-Databases.aspx) article by John West.

> For clones in the Master databases, Sitecore uses the __Source
>   (Sitecore.FieldIDs.Source) field defined in the Advanced section of
>   the standard template to store the URI of the cloned item

Also gives you some example code for a publishing pipleline.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498534/how-to-provide-email-notifications-workflows-for-clones) about identifying clones and using a custom workflow to send notifications along with code samples and links to additional SDN discussions on the subject should cover all you need.

Comment: When I modify the source item, there is no such flag that lets me know that it has been modified.

Comment: This field allows you to find cloned items, you'd need to look in the links DB for all referenced ID's in the source field.

Comment: What aspect do you need to control?